# Apache IP-Based Access Control. Allow, Deny, Order Confusion

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

This should be an easy one, but I am seeing conflicting information from google, and would like some clarification. I am trying to block access to a site to all but 1 IP address.

I am adding `Allow`, `Deny` and `Order` directives to the **sites-enabled** directory. Which of the following is correct?

```
Order allow, deny
Allow From <ip>
```

or

```
Order deny, allow
Deny From all
Allow From <ip>
```

Comment: Rather than Google for the answer why don't you read the Apache documentation instead?

Comment: Instead of posting snarky responses like RTFM or Google it, add a succinct answer so that when people DO Google this question and come here they get more than your snark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily find an example in [apache documentation page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html).

This is taken from the referenced page:

*In the following example, all hosts in the apache.org domain are allowed access; all other hosts are denied access.*

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from apache.org
```

So, your 2nd config is the right one.